# Achieve S3 concurrency in scala by splitting send and receive into promise and future without blocking

Tags: scala, concurrency, amazon-s3, akka

What is a suitable scala library for performing massively concurrent S3 calls,
and where can I find sample code showing how the library is used?
I have been searching and experimenting for days without discovering a sufficient solution.

A number of libraries implement S3 calls as discrete blocking calls.
Others implement them as threaded blocking calls.
Some hint at the potential of supporting promises/futures but give insufficient examples.

Simplified question:
How do I send S3 a URL, header, and body and immediately return
and when S3 responds, I want to pick up the response in context.

Full question:
How do I construct 1000 URLs, headers, and bodies, send them, and immediately return
and when each response arrives, connect the response with the correct recipient.

Amongst the libraries I have tried (not exhaustive) are the following:

- dispatch (still the most likely candidate)
- akka.dispatch
- jets3t
- s3lib

Any responses are welcome.

Comment: Are you asking in context of Play framework ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/dispatch/reboot built on NIO.

To use this you can do something as simple as

```
import dispatch._

def foo = {
  val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
  val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
  val length = for (c <- country) yield c.length
}
```

You can do this within parallel collections and since these are all unblocking promised .. For example to do this 1000 times parallely enter the following

```
(1 to 1000).par.foreach(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the first look at the code Apache Async HttpClient is truly async

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-asyncclient-dev/examples.html

You can write a simple wrapper that creates a Scala future from completion handler

You can also look at Grizzly/Netty powered http clients